# Putting terminal prompt in new row, after <username@host-path>

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, prompt

How to modify terminal prompt on Linux (specifically Ubuntu), so that prompt is in new row after **username@host-path**?
Like on the picture below (git bash terminal on win7):

[image]

Comment: Off-topic here... try [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is detailed page that should help you
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt

And to directly answer your question:
In your .bashrc file, located in your home directory, find any entry that ends with `\$` and add a newline to it so that it would end with `\n\$`.

Comment: Thanks, easier than I thought.